# Unable to read in a string as ASCII or UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

If I check the charset of a file that I'm reading from I get:

```
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

So I am reading it in like:

```
File.open(@file_path, r:ASCII) do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    line = line.rstrip.force_encoding("ASCII")
```

Which works fine until I hit this line:

```
"Seat 2: tchin\xE9 ($423 in chips)"
```

Where I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

This line looks like this in my text editor:

```
"Seat 2: tchin? ($423 in chips)"
```

If I try reading it in as UTF-8 instead of ASCII, I get the same error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Any ideas of what I should be doing.  I have tried using iconv to convert it from ASCII to UTF-8 and and I get this error:

```
Iconv::IllegalSequence: "\xE9 ($423 in chips"
```

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding (max 127, 128 characters), not 8 bit (max 255, 256 characters).

E9 (Decimal 233, probably a *é*) is higher then 128. So you have no ASCII, the ruby error message is correct. 
I expect it is cp1252.

**Update:**
I'm quiet sure, it is a *é*. The sentence *"Seat 2: tchiné ($423 in chips)"* makes sense (I don't know what it is, but it seems to be something in Poker.

> This line looks like this in my text editor:
>
> ```
> "Seat 2: tchin? ($423 in chips)"
> ```

Your editor may not display the *é*, so it displays a substitute character.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file as "r:ISO8859-1" worked.